# Woocommerce: Multiple Shipping Classes for one product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

First of all, thanks to everyone for your contribution to stackoverflow - you helped me hundreds of times. Now, I really have a question I can't find. :(

I'm using the latest Woocommerce for Wordpress. In Woocommerce you can create shipping-classes and assign them to the products you upload. This helps you for creating "complex" shipping methods.

However, I wan't a very complex shipping method. How can I make it possible that I can choose multiple shipping-classes per product and not just one? I am not an expert in programming :(

I'm using table rate shipping also. So what my final goal is:

**Product A:**
Shipping-Class - local post rates

**Product B:**
Shipping Class - Chinese Warehouse
Shipping-Class - local post rates

Why I want this?

I have a warehouse in Thailand and one in China. People ordering products and some I have to collect from the Chinese Warehouse. The Products from China will come to my place and there I will put them in the same box as those products from my local warehouse. Currently my shipping system thinks "This dude makes two boxes and send two boxes to one customer". So my customer has to pay way to much delivery. I need to be able to tell my programm that I order from different warehouses but in the end I put all together in one box.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you make a shipping method that combines the two with a combined rate?

Comment: That is what I actually want, but it is not possible with the plugin I am using (Table Rate Shipping from Bolder Elements). So, that's why somehow I strongly believe that this can be done if I can add more shipping-classes to one product. Currently you just can asign one shipping-class to a product. I am planning to add methods per shipping class and than asign "standard shipping" to products in Thai Warehouse and "Standard Shipping" + "Import from China to Thailand" to products from the Chinese Warehouse. So I calculate the import costs for Chinese Products + total cart weight for local post

Comment: I just read that when using the Table Rate Plugin, instead of choosing PER Order in the calculation Type setting, you can choose Calculate Per Row or Calculate Per Class. Have you tried this option?

Comment: I am using to calculate per class. My customers (based in Thailand and we just sell within Thailand) don't know from which warehouse they are ordering. So the cart is a mix up of products from thai and chinese warehouse. Info Example:

1-5kg = 10$ (local delivery)
5-10kg = 12$ (local delivery)

Now the cart has 5kg Products from local warehouse and 5kg from chinese warehouse. Total shipping costs = $12, instead of $10. My cart treats the two classes as two sepperate parcels. :( I am so sorry, I don't know how to explain it easier :)

Comment: Ups sorry, my comment above is wrong. Situation now: $20 delivery cost instead of $12